# SAPUI5: How to fire an event when a value inside of a model change?

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.Input and I use `bindProperty` function to bind its `maxLength` property to a model.

In this way I can change this property easily by changing the value in the model. (Actually it is maximum length of the postal code)

Now I need to call a function as soon as the value of this property is changed inside of the model.

Is there any even that can be attach to value change event of a property in a JSON model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Model is extended from `sap.ui.model.Model`.
There you have a [Method](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.model.Model/methods) to register an EventHandler for propertyChange

```
attachPropertyChange(function() { /* do some stuff */ }, oContext)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I want to do vice versa. I want to change the value of the model. Then this change causes the `maxLength` of my sap.m.Input change. I want to set an Event on the Input field and not on Model. I want when the maxLength of the Input change then event fire.